# how should I convert string to integer and sum the list?

Tags: python

I want to sum up the list of string. I tried to convert strings to integers by using for loop and int(). But it didn't work. What should I do? Thank you for your answer!

```
a = ['1','2','3']
total = 0
for i in a:
    int(i)
    total = total + i

print(total) #expected output:6
```

Comment: `int(i)` returns the integer value, `i` remains being the string it was before. You need
`total = total + int(i)`

Comment: `int` doesn't change the argument. `i=int(i)` should do what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `str` and `int` data types are immutable, so functions called on them **can never modify their values**.

Hence the `int()` function can't modify your `i` variable in the for-loop [nor is it supposed to.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int)

As a result, the `int()` function is *designed to return a new integer*, thus you must assign it somewhere or it will be "lost in the void".

I.e.

```
a = ['1', '2', '3']
total = 0
for i in a:
    total = total + int(i)

print(total)
```

---

Note that it is great practice to learn these, albeit simple, algorithms for operations on lists, strings etc, but the [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) built-in function is there to be used if your in a rush!

```
a = ['1', '2', '3']
print(sum([int(i) for i in a]))
```

*N.B. I have also used a list-comprehension here that you may not be familiar with; they are **really** useful, I suggest learning them.*

Answer (score 9):

Use [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) with [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to map each item to int:

```
a = ['1','2','3']

print(sum(map(int, a)))
# 6
```

---

`int(i)` as such does not alter `i` unless you assign it back. So your code should be:

```
for i in a:
    i = int(i)
    total = total + i
```

Or, shortly:

```
for i in a:
    total = total + int(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = ['1','2','3']
total = 0
for i in a:
    total = total + int(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why everyone suggests loops. Imo the pythonic way would be the following:

```
total = sum([int(x) for x in a])
```

May be a bit heavier on RAM as compared to the `total +=...` with for loop approach but I'd wager it's faster.

EDIT:
As @tevemadar pointed out you can actually do:

```
total = sum((int(x) for x in a))
```

which changes the list comprehension to be a generator that you then sum, which is a better solution as it does away with having to have the list in memory as one.

EDIT2:
A thing to watch out for with the second solution is that changing `a` after defining `total` actually influences `total`.

Comment: You could write `sum((int(x) for x in a))`, and eliminate memory concerns. But I mainly wanted to write about the remark: explaining the problem with the existing code and fixing it with minimal changes also has value, that is why.

Comment: @tevemadar Oh damn I thought tuple comprehensions weren't a thing. I tried it out and getting a generator is pretty much perfect. Well TIL, thanks, I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: Can you explain "EDIT2" part? I don't think changing `a` after the definition will alter `total`.

Answer (score 1):

(Implementing the comment)
`int(i)` returns the integer value, `i` remains being the string it was before.
You need `total = total + int(i)`:

```
a = ['1','2','3']
total = 0
for i in a:
    total = total + int(i)

print(total) # output:6
```